# Coverage of code called by service bus in Web Application

Tags: c#, azure, code-coverage, servicebus

I am using dot cover for measuring coverage of my web application. I am using Service bus for processing messages recieved in an Async method.

I am not able to get coverage of async method called by Service bus but I am only able to get coverage of REST API's called.

Is there any way that I can get coverage of code called by service bus?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way that I can get coverage of code called by service bus?

The async method will not be executed until a new message being inserted into the Service Bus topic.

If you ran unit testing and calculated code coverage, you could add messages to the topic before run invoke the async method in your unit testing.

If you did the manual coverage. You could write a new application which could insert messages to the same topic which subscribed by your web application. You also need to run this application before test your web application. It will ensure that there are some messages in the topic and the async method will be executed when you test your web application.

For how to add message to Service Bus topic, link below is for your reference.

[Send messages to the topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions#4-send-messages-to-the-topic)